# Can not connect to localhost while creating own web server

Tags: c, webserver

I have created web server, and while I want to test it. 
I typed in https://localhost:8080/test.html in browser(Chrome, also I use macbook pro).
The browser displays ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

If someone could help me to explain and solve this kind of situation, it will be really helpful. I have tried running this program on either linux and macOS environment, none of them works. I have already searched a lot of similar solution online, however, none of them could solve my problem. Thank you guys.

My code is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h> // just added
#include <netdb.h>//Network address and service translation
#include <arpa/inet.h> //For message type convertion
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include <sys/signal.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define BUFFSIZE 2048

// port number
int port_num = 8080;

void handle(int fd) {
    printf("handle function.\n");
    char buff[BUFFSIZE + 1];
    int bytes_read = read(fd, buff, BUFFSIZE);
    printf("bytes_read: %d\n", bytes_read);
    if (bytes_read <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "connection failed, or read failed.\n");
    }
    printf("Msg: %s\n", buff);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    // make sure get the port num
    /*
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Improper number of arguments used\n");
        exit(1);
    }else {
        port_num = atoi(argv[1]);
    }
    */
    // setup socket
    struct sockaddr_in server_address, client_address;
    socklen_t client_address_length = sizeof(client_address);

    // socket file descriptor
    int fd_server, fd_client;

    char buf[BUFFSIZE];
    int on = 1;

    fd_server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (fd_server < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: socket set up failed.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // I don't know what is this
    setsockopt(fd_server, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &on, sizeof(int));

    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(port_num);
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    // binding
    if (bind(fd_server, (struct sockaddr *)&server_address, sizeof(server_address)) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: binding failed.\n");
        exit(1);
    }


    // listen 
    if (listen(fd_server, 10) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: socket listen failed.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (1) {
        // accept

        fd_client = accept(fd_server, (struct sockaddr *)&client_address, &client_address_length);
        if (fd_client == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: accept failed.\n");
            continue;
        }
        printf("connected...\n");
        int pid = fork();
        if (!fork()) {
            // child process
            close(fd_server);

            memset(buf, 0, 2048);
            read(fd_client, buf, 2047);
            printf("%s\n", buf);
            close(fd_client);
            printf("closing...\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        close(fd_client);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And after I hit the url(https://localhost:8080/test.html), it prints 
[image]

Comment: Why are you forking twice for each client??

Comment: assuming your socket is listening correctly, there's much more to a webserver than simply opening a socket. I don't see any http protocol responding messages at all. Furthermore, the s in https is for "sercure", meaning the conversation is encrypted. Any https session is going to start with some kind of key negotiation and key exchange .. your webserver here isn't doing any of that for your browser, so your browser is going to give up after a timeout.

Comment: @MartinJames my mistake, I didn't comment it.

Comment: @yano you are the one who solve my problem. I typed  http://localhost:8080/test.html instead, and I got the message I wanted. Thank you!!!

Comment: @TonyYang Please don't show an image of text. Copy&paste the text to the question.

Comment: learn about the HTTP protocol and the information required that you have to send with each request/response

Comment: you need to change the test in line `if (!fork())`  by `if (!pid)` as you are doing a second fork, and you have two processes acting as the parent.  You need also to check for the possibility of `fork(2)` failing (it gives you a negative number, different from `0`)

Comment: OT: regarding: `int port_num = 8080;`   Port numbers are 16bit values, suggest: `short int port_num = 8080;`

Comment: regarding: `int bytes_read = read(fd, buff, BUFFSIZE);
    printf("bytes_read: %d\n", bytes_read); `int bytes_read = read(fd, buff, BUFFSIZE);
    if (bytes_read <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "connection failed, or read failed.\n");
    }
    printf("Msg: %s\n", buff);`  1) `read()` returns a `ssize_t`, not a `int`  2) `read()` does not NUL terminate the input data, so need to insert a statement after: ` `int bytes_read = read(fd, buff, BUFFSIZE);` such as: `buff[ bytes_read ] = '\0';`  otherwise the statement: `printf("Msg: %s\n", buff);` will result in undefined behavior.  (cont)

Comment: (cont) when the call to `read()` fails, after outputting the error message to `stderr` should cleanup and exit.  BTW: a returned count of 0 is NOT an error, it just means the client closed the connection.  Note: `read()` sets `errno`, so a better way to handle the outputting of the error message would be: `perror( "read failed" );`

Comment: regarding:  `server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(port_num);
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;`  Should set all of `server_address` to 0x00 before setting those three fields

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- first of all, you are calling `fork()` twice in your main loop, so you create two subprocesses for each connection, while you had to check the value given and stored in `pid` variable.
- second, you don't know why to call `setsockopts` to reuse the address given by the socket... and you are right.  It is of no use here... I have commented it.

I have made a first attempt, by doing this changes:

```
     // I don't know what is this
-    setsockopt(fd_server, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &on, sizeof(int));
+    // setsockopt(fd_server, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &on, sizeof(int)); // indeed, you had better not to use it.
```

and

```
         printf("connected...\n");
         int pid = fork();
-        if (!fork()) {
+        if (!pid) { // check for the value of pid, not call fork() again.
             // child process
             close(fd_server);
```

After this, I get this output:

```
[s000]lcu@Luiss-MacBook-Pro:~/so/59935716$ pru
connected...
connected...
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: es,en;q=0.9
Cookie: tocTree_ref-topic-group:ref-group-resources:ref-group-jdbc:ref-group-jdbcconnectionpools:ref-jdbcconnectionpoolnew1Text-hi=tocTree:ref-topic-group:ref-group-resources:ref-group-jdbc:ref-group-jdbcconnectionpools:ref-jdbcconnectionpoolnew1:ref-jdbcconnectionpoolnew1_link; tocTree-hi=tocTree:ref-topic-group:ref-group-configuration:ref-group-connectionservice; JSESSIONID=2d890f14dcdd285f478653a16a62; treeForm_tree-hi=treeForm:tree:resources:JDBC:connectionPoolResources


closing...
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: es,en;q=0.9
Cookie: tocTree_ref-topic-group:ref-group-resources:ref-group-jdbc:ref-group-jdbcconnectionpools:ref-jdbcconnectionpoolnew1Text-hi=tocTree:ref-topic-group:ref-group-resources:ref-group-jdbc:ref-group-jdbcconnectionpools:ref-jdbcconnectionpoolnew1:ref-jdbcconnectionpoolnew1_link; tocTree-hi=tocTree:ref-topic-group:ref-group-configuration:ref-group-connectionservice; JSESSIONID=2d890f14dcdd285f478653a16a62; treeForm_tree-hi=treeForm:tree:resources:JDBC:connectionPoolResources


closing...
connected...
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: es,en;q=0.9
Cookie: tocTree_ref-topic-group:ref-group-resources:ref-group-jdbc:ref-group-jdbcconnectionpools:ref-jdbcconnectionpoolnew1Text-hi=tocTree:ref-topic-group:ref-group-resources:ref-group-jdbc:ref-group-jdbcconnectionpools:ref-jdbcconnectionpoolnew1:ref-jdbcconnectionpoolnew1_link; tocTree-hi=tocTree:ref-topic-group:ref-group-configuration:ref-group-connectionservice; JSESSIONID=2d890f14dcdd285f478653a16a62; treeForm_tree-hi=treeForm:tree:resources:JDBC:connectionPoolResources


closing...
```

(as you see, google chrome tries to do three connection attempts to the server)

After some revisión, I have made the following changes in your code, leading to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h> // just added
#include <netdb.h>//Network address and service translation
#include <arpa/inet.h> //For message type convertion
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include <sys/signal.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define BUFFSIZE 2048

// port number
int port_num = 8080;

void handle(int fd) {
    printf("handle function.\n");
    char buff[BUFFSIZE + 1];
    int bytes_read = read(fd, buff, BUFFSIZE);
    printf("bytes_read: %d\n", bytes_read);
    if (bytes_read <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "connection failed, or read failed.\n");
    }
    printf("Msg: %s\n", buff);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    // make sure get the port num
    /*
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Improper number of arguments used\n");
        exit(1);
    }else {
        port_num = atoi(argv[1]);
    }
    */
    // setup socket
    struct sockaddr_in server_address, client_address;
    socklen_t client_address_length = sizeof(client_address);

    // socket file descriptor
    int fd_server, fd_client;

    char buf[BUFFSIZE];
    int on = 1;

    fd_server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (fd_server < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: socket set up failed.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // I don't know what is this
    // setsockopt(fd_server, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &on, sizeof(int)); // indeed, you had better not to use it.

    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(port_num);
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    // binding
    if (bind(fd_server, (struct sockaddr *)&server_address, sizeof(server_address)) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: binding failed.\n");
        exit(1);
    }


    // listen 
    if (listen(fd_server, 10) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: socket listen failed.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // accept
    while ((fd_client = accept(fd_server, (struct sockaddr *)&client_address, &client_address_length)) >= 0) {
        printf("connected...\n"); // do this only in the child process. Or flush stdout before forking...
        fflush(stdout); // so you get only one message (you flush the buffer before forking)
        int pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0) { // check for the value of pid, not call fork() again.
            // child process
            close(fd_server);  // good.

            memset(buf, 0, 2048);
            ssize_t n = read(fd_client, buf, sizeof buf);
            if (n > 0) {
                write(1, buf, n);  // better not consider it a null terminated string.
            }
            close(fd_client);
            printf("closing...\n");
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
        close(fd_client); // good.
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "Error: accept failed.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

I have not checked the `handle()` function, as it is not used in the main code.

You will get the different versions of this code from [here](https://github.com/mojadita/so/tree/master/59935716).